# Xcode 9 error After installing Realm in react native for local storage

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, react-native, xcode9.1

Xcode 9 error after installing Realm in React-Native for local storage.

> *can't exec `'myPath/Source/node_modules/realm/src/../scripts/ccache-clang.sh'`
>   (Permission denied), failed with exit code 71*.

Help me to resolve this error.

Thanks

Comment: I am also having the same issue. Any resolution found ?

Answer (score 0):

1. I think you can upgrade your version of realm to the [latest version](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/react-native/).
2. Or I have a work around solution for you: Open the Xcode project, find ...
   and remove this line: **"$(SRCROOT)/../../../../ios/Pods/Headers/Public/"**

Here is the picture after removed:

[image]